# How can I prove that the following function is increasing in $x \in [0,1]$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, power-series, polylogarithm, monotone-functions

How can I prove that the following function is increasing in $x$: $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x (1-x) ^ {i-1} \log \left (1+ \mu (1-x)^{i-1} \right)$$

where $\mu$ is any non-negative number and $x$ is in $[0,1]$?

Comment: You can differentiate with respect to $x$ through the sum.

Comment: Is false. If x=0 or x=1, the sum is 0. If is increasing, must be 0 for all x, abs

Comment: No, the sum at x=1 is the maximum. Only the first term of the summation will be non-zero. So for x=0 it is zero, but for x=1 is equal to $\log(1+\mu)$ (which is the maximum value of this summation)

Comment: Differentiating will not take us anywhere, since it will be an infinite summation with mixed terms (with logarithm and fractions),

Comment: @Patrik if x=1 the term (1-x) is 0, then the sum is 0

Comment: @vvnitram but the first term has (1-x)^0=1, so the first term is the only term which lives when x=1.